# PHP embedding text on a image

Tags: php

I'm trying to embed text on a image.I'm using this script http://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html

This works for fine with one text.Say for eg: I want text some thing like this

textone
texttwo
textthree

I want them one below one.How can this be achieved.i tried to use

```
<p>$handlerData = "textone"; ?></p><p>$handlerData = "texttwo"; ?></p><p>$handlerData = "textthree"; ?></p>
```

But this is only embedding first text.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem with this currently is that it should be <p><?php $handlerData = "textone"; ?></p><p><?php $handlerData = "texttwo"; ?></p>

Answer (score 0):

You would use the return character for your OS (\r, \n, or \r\n). HTML won't be rendered by PHP/GD.

[Edit]
The code you have posted doesn't do anything related to overlaying text on an image, but you would want your variable (in this case $handlerData) to contain carriage return characters to break the line:

```
$handlerData = "textone \r\n"
.              "texttwo \r\n"
.              "textthree \r\n";
```

This may even work:

```
$handlerData = "textone
texttwo
textthree ";
```

but you will have stray white space due to tabs and whatnot. If this doesn't work, you will need to post your actual code

Comment: :I'm only getting first text,how will i make all the text to appear.it would be great,if you can make change to my code.

Comment: :how do i position them.Can i use padding.How do i use padding on variable.Thank you.I've to postion each one on different positions

Answer (score 0):

You can use \n

```
$handlerData = 'textone'."\n".'texttwo'."\n".'textthree';
```

Or you can change the function like that:

```
function watermarkImage ($source, $text, $destination, $x = 10, $y = 20) { 
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($source);
   $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
   $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
   imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 
   $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
   $font = 'arial.ttf';
   $font_size = 10; 
   imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);
   if ($DestinationFile<>'') {
      imagejpeg ($image_p, $destination, 100); 
   } else {
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
   };
   imagedestroy($image); 
   imagedestroy($image_p); 
};
```

You can now use $x and $y to position the text.

Comment: :how do i position them.Can i use padding.How do i use padding on variable.Thank you.I've to postion each one on different positions.

Comment: To position them, you modify $x and $y. For instance, if you want to position them one over the other, you do watermarkImage('path/to/image',''text1','path/to/image',10,20); and then watermarkImage('path/to/image',''text2','path/to/image',10,30); !Notice that i modified the $y variable, so that the next text written is 10 px lower.